# Convert Sub-List of Strings to Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have some data that looks like:

```
[['Alpha: Whiskey',
  'Bravo: 50',
  'Charlie: Tango',
  'Delta: 100',
  'Echo: Foxtrot'],
 ['Alpha: Zulu',
  'Bravo: 25',
  'Charlie: November',
  'Delta: 50',
  'Echo: Uniform'],
 ['Alpha: Papa',
  'Bravo: 10',
  'Charlie: Mike',
  'Delta: 20',
  'Echo: Sierra']]
```

I would like to convert it to be a list of dictionaries, like so:

```
[{'Alpha: Whiskey',
  'Bravo: 50',
  'Charlie: Tango',
  'Delta: 100',
  'Echo: Foxtrot'},
 {'Alpha: Zulu',
  'Bravo: 25',
  'Charlie: November',
  'Delta: 50',
  'Echo: Uniform'},
 {'Alpha: Papa',
  'Bravo: 10',
  'Charlie: Mike',
  'Delta: 20',
  'Echo: Sierra'}]
```

It feels like I am very much so over-complicating things, but I was originally planning to split each string on the ':', everything before becomes the key, and everything after becomes the value, but I am having a hard time putting it into production. Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: The code you say would like to be a list of dictionaries is not. It's actually a list of sets. I assume there are lot of missing `'` to separate the keys from the values.

Comment: Stacks gotten a bit more hostile since the last time I used it. If I'm being honest, I've spent a fair bit of time on it so far. I had my code pasted in the original submission but thought I would get a more unbiased response by not pasting it. Either way, feedback noted.

Comment: please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

This will create the dictionary.

```
my_dict = [dict((item.split(":") for item in sub_lst)) for sub_lst in lst]
```

This will remove the extra spaces from dictionary keys and values.

```
lst_of_dict = [
    {key.strip(): value.strip() for key, value in d.items()} for d in lst_of_dict
]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. The first part works as intended. The second portion, to remove white space, unpacks each nested dictionary so each line becomes it's own dictionary. Not sure if that makes sense. I end up with 15 individual dictionaries in a list, instead of 3 dictionaries in a list.

Comment: @Jess fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```js
list = [['Alpha: Whiskey',
  'Bravo: 50',
  'Charlie: Tango',
  'Delta: 100',
  'Echo: Foxtrot'],
 ['Alpha: Zulu',
  'Bravo: 25',
  'Charlie: November',
  'Delta: 50',
  'Echo: Uniform'],
 ['Alpha: Papa',
  'Bravo: 10',
  'Charlie: Mike',
  'Delta: 20',
  'Echo: Sierra']]

new_list = []

for i in range(len(list)):
    new_dictionary = {}
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        splited = list[i][j].split(': ')
        new_dictionary[splited[0]] = splited[1]
    new_list.append(new_dictionary)

print(new_list)
```